# ember.js pushObject not pushing

Tags: ember.js

Getting my brain wrapped around emberjs.  Trying to create a controller that loads objects from a webservice call that returns a JSON array:

*(Note that this is javascript generated from coffeescript)*

```js
MTM.Trade.controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  loadAll: function() {
    var self;
    self = this;
    this.set('content', []); /* fails with or without this line*/
    return $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/webservice/trades', function(data) {
      var jsonTrade, trade, _i, _len;
      console.log("Length = " + data.length);
      for (_i = 0, _len = data.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        jsonTrade = data[_i];
        trade = MTM.Trade.create(jsonTrade);
        self.pushObject(trade);
      }
      console.log("Everything pushed");
    });
  }
});
```

Upon calling `MTM.Trade.controller.loadAll()`, it's clear that the loop is being called for each object.  However my controller never changes.. running `console.log MTM.Trade.controller.get('content')` returns a blank array.

I know that ember-rest and ember-data exist, but for now I'm rolling-my-own to learn how to do these things myself, and the will migrate to those frameworks later.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [this article](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/03/18/emberjs-collections/) I did get the answer to my question.. I need to init my array as such:

```js
MTM.Trade.controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    return this.set('content', Ember.A());
  },

loadAll: function() {
    ...
```

So now my question is, why?  Intuitively shouldn't the `ArrayController` initializer take care of this?  Perhaps this is not the way an `ArrayController` is expected to be used?

Comment: FYI this was discussed at further length here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your update, I put a comment, where I told you to initialize the content at creation time (so in the hash of the create).

```js
MTM.Trade.controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    //...
});
```

But then I saw that you were setting `content` to `[]` in the loadAll function. So I was thinking that initialization was unnecessary.

When looking closest to `ArrayController`, it's just an extension of the `ArrayProxy` mixin, (ie: kinds of interface), so when creating an instance of an `ArrayController`, you must define the `content` property.

Comment: Thx sly.  Seems to me that since this would be a common use case that ArrayController would go slightly beyond simply extending ArrayProxy and instantiate itself.  Maybe I'll make a pull request..?

Comment: Perhaps you can. But what I understand, is that ArrayProxy could wrap any kind of array-like object. I think this behavior would be kept, but perhaps at creation time, if the `content` property is not defined by user, then, it is simply set to `[]`. The other solution could be to explicitly throw an error telling the user he must define the `content` property of the ArrayProxy (and consequently, of the ArrayController)

Comment: Since ArrayProxy is a mixin I wouldn't want to make the change there, but I agree that ArrayController should definitely set the content to [] if it's not explicitly set.

Comment: Yep, I agree not to make the change on the mixins, but on implementations Classes, in this case in the ArrayController.